# Why my recycler View is not Showing anything

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show all my users. it's not showing even a single of them. I do not know why but my adapter is not working and I also even tried the adapter.startlistening() method. but do not know where to put it. could anyone please just help me?

```
public class AllUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView allUsersList;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_users);
        allUsersList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.users_list);
        allUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        allUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    }    
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                .setQuery(databaseReference, Users.class)
                .build();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.single_user_layout, parent,false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, int i, Users users) {
                usersViewHolder.setName(users.getName());
            }
        };

        allUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: A call to `adapter.startlistening()` is needed before the adapter starts reading and synchronizing data from the database. You should place this call where you want it to start reading, in your case likely at the end of `onStart()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is the database:

```
Users
|
|---------UID1
          ---name
          ---image
          ---.....

----------UID2
          ---name
          ---image
          ---......
```

Make sure that your class `Users` has the fields exactly like in the database:

```
class Users{

//these fields must be typed exactly like in the database (watch out for upper case and lower case)

private String name;
private String image;
.........
.........

//also must have a constructor for all fields

//also must have getters and setters for all fields

}
```

Also in `onStart()` add this line:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Directly under this line:

```
allUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```